# Show that $x\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=0$ when g$\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$ = $f({\frac{x}{y}})$

Tags: partial-derivative

Can I compute $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ to be $\frac{df}{dx}$? 
The reason is I think $\mathit{f}$ is a one variable function.
So $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{1}{y}f'$$ and $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=\frac{df}{dy} = \frac{-x}{y^2}f'$$

Comment: What does $g\binom{x}{y}$ means? I think that is $g(x,y)$. Then use Euler's theorem of homogeneous function differentiation. See, $g(tx, ty)=t^{0}g(x,y)$.

Comment: @Alapan Das Thanks, $$g\binom{x}{y}$$ means g(x, y). I will search about this theorem.

Comment: @Alapan Das I have a question. In this case, if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable , can I say $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is also differentiable?

Comment: Your solution is alright, you can interchange the two, as when you take partial derivatives, you are assuming the other variable is constant